# Stop Runtime when last agent enters the sink

Tags: anylogic

how can I model that the runtime the runtime of a simulation is stoped when the last agent of a limited number of agents created from a source  enters the sink node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a variable numberAgentsToCreate of type integer, where you store the amount of limited agents to be created by the source.

You can either break or end the simulation, or completely exit it.
In the OnEnter code of the sink block, use the following code:

```
if(self.count()>=numberAgentsToCreate){
    getEngine().pause(); //to pause model execution
    //getEngine().finish(); //to end the model execution
    //getEngine().stop(); //to destroy the model
}
```

[image: Automatic stop at sink count]